# how to search and replace tag text in HTML file based on text instead of line no

Tags: bash

How do i search a particular line based on string match and replace it with another sting.
Below is the example of a html strong which i need to modify using bash script.

```
< link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://teststore.xxx.com/store/downpanel.css">
```

change to:

```
< link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://testsstore.xxx.com/store/downpanel.css">
```

i.e  teststore  with testsstore.  just trying to add 's' .

I guess i need to match all the string.  because downpanel.css is the one which differentiate which line to be edit with 's'.

I being said that this can be achieved by Regualar expression.. but i couldn't able to make it .  any help with syntax would be highly greatful.

thanks.
jack

Comment: Ob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 : don't use regex to match HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace **all** occurrences of this link, just do

```
sed 's_"https://teststore.xxx.com/store/downpanel.css"_"https://testsstore.xxx.com/store/downpanel.css"_g' old_file > new_file
```

If you really need to match the whole part you show, then put in in the `sed` command. Beware of line breaks, they will spoil the match if encountered somewhere in the middle.

Here's a [reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1) for `sed`. Or just type `man sed` on Linux.

Comment: thanks all of you.. ..sed 's_"https://teststore.xxx.com/store/downpanel.css"_"https://testsstore.xxx.com/store/downpanel.css"_g' did worked as i was trying.

Comment: @Johnbritto: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

To solve problems like this you generally use a `sed` construct like this:

```
sed -e '/unique pattern/s/string or pattern/replacement string/' file
```

The initial `/unique pattern/` part constrains the substitution to lines which the pattern given. For simple cases, like yours, it may be sufficient to simply perform the substitution on all lines containing `teststore`, thus the unique pattern part can be omitted and the substitute becomes global:

```
sed -e 's/teststore/testsstore/' file
```

If this is a problem for you and replaces something it should not you can use the original form, perhaps like this:

```
sed -e '/link.*teststore/s/teststore/testsstore/' file
```

To help limit the impact.

Note that this will only write the modified version of `file` to stdout. To make the change in place, add the `-i` switch to `sed`.